# TypeScript error with Symbol.species example from MDN

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

With this code (which is equivalent to a sample at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species)):

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return MyArray }
}
```

I get this error (with `TypeScript 3.8.3`):

```
Class static side 'typeof MyArray' incorrectly extends base class static side '{ isArray(arg: any): arg is any[]; readonly prototype: any[]; from<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>): T[]; from<T, U>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>, mapfn: (v: T, k: number) => U, thisArg?: any): U[]; from<T>(iterable: Iterable<...> | ArrayLike<...>): T[]; from<T, U>(iterable: Iterable<...> | ArrayLike<...>, mapfn: (v: T, k: nu...'.
  Types of property '[Symbol.species]' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof MyArray' is not assignable to type 'ArrayConstructor'.
      Type 'typeof MyArray' provides no match for the signature '(arrayLength?: number | undefined): any[]'.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: `static get [Symbol.species]() { return MyArray }` is actually a default in this case, so you can omit this line

Comment: the code you provided is not the same as the MDN code you said so your question is not very helpful for future readers of SO

Comment: @Rachid Oussanaa: I did not say the same, I said "equivalent" to the MDN code sample. There is no reason why another constructor cannot be used in place of `Array`, which in fact is the whole point of implementing the symbol.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Wether it is the default or not, I want to know why the type checking fails.

Comment: The problem is that es6 class implementation can never be callable, so you can't satisfy ArrayConstructor definition. I guess you can just ts-ignore this line if you really need it for whatever reason

Comment: as said @AlekseyL. if you want your code to work just cast `MyArray`,  like `static get [Symbol.species](): ArrayConstructor { return <ArrayConstructor>MyArray }`

Comment: [TS seems confused about the type of the constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBBATss8A8AVAfNApgB4Au+AdgCYwpqa7QDeAUNK9MAPZkTHICuwYh2QAKQgH4AXNDJ8AtgCN8yaAB9ofSvgBmASzL4KASkYs25iHwAOysUYDcZ1gF8mrpsXg3oAYSEqAXmgRMFR0ABlyAHNiAAspGXklFXVNCh19QxMAvDAyeABtAF1HTm5iaEJpP2FoIJp0Uq4eaHhq-zq4JDD4eyA) It claims that `Array` satisfies `arrayLength?: number | undefined) => any[];` and complains that `MyArray` doesn't but the `super` in the `MyArray` constructor doesn't have that signature at all.

Comment: Hmm, I've been poking this a bit more and I suspect the issue is that TS isn't exactly sure the class constructor is the same as the array constructor. Likely because it doesn't consider that the class constructor will be called with `new` it expects it to be called like a normal function, and you cannot call `MyArray(7)`, for example, you *can* call `Array(7)`, though, since it's a constructor function.

Comment: It just checks constructors "assignability" and `typeof MyArray` is indeed not assignable to type `ArrayConstructor` because es6 class can't be callable (can't implement `(arrayLength?: number | undefined): any[]` for example). Of course this doesn't mean it can't be used in `get [Symbol.species]`, but typescript just have no way to know this