# Overriding Promise implementation to Bluebird.Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, bluebird

I've got a scenario where promise will be undefined for some remote executions of a code base. Locally, it's running Node. Remotely, its running another runtime that doesn't have Promises. Bluebird works fine, but I'd like to override Promise for all files if it is undefined.

Something like:

```
import { Promise as BlueBirdPromise } from 'bluebird';

if (!Promise) {
    Promise = BlueBirdPromise;
    Promise.setScheduler((fn: any) => {
        setTimeout(fn, 0);
    });
}
```

The above code doesn't work as Promise and BlueBirdPromise are different types. I believe Promise is an interface in TS.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Example:

```
import { Promise as BlueBirdPromise } from 'bluebird';

BlueBirdPromise.setScheduler((fn: any) => {
    setTimeout(fn, 0);
});
// eslint-disable-next-line
Promise = BlueBirdPromise;
```

Error:

```
polyfills.ts:13:1 - error TS2741: Property '[Symbol.species]' is missing in type 'typeof Bluebird' but required in type 'PromiseConstructor'.
```

Comment: "*The above code doesn't work as Promise and BlueBirdPromise are different types.*" I'd have thought that it doesn't work because if `Promise` is missing in an environment, `!Promise` will throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: Correct - the above is just pseudocode (ish). The if conditional isn't the crux - just an example of that i'm looking to do here.

Comment: OK. However, the pseudocode-ish example makes it hard to figure out what the actual problem you face is. Can you not assign `BlueBirdPromise` to `Promise`? If so, *why* - what is the compiler error?

Comment: The error is: `Property '[Symbol.species]' is missing in type 'typeof Bluebird' but required in type 'PromiseConstructor'`

Comment: TS does struggle with `Symbol.species` and constructors: [TypeScript error with Symbol.species example from MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61985340)

Comment: I was able to solve it. I updated my question with the solution.

Comment: Solutions should be posted as an answer, not be part of a question.

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this by overriding the Promise definition bound to the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object). This is done in the `index.js` file before any main code is executed.

Locally, Visual Studio Code will recognize `Promise` as its default type. However, when executed, this block will override the default `Promise` definition with that provided by `Bluebird`.

In this way, any use of `Promise` will use `Bluebird` over Node's definition. Or, in the case of the remote runtime not being node, provide an implementation where there is none.

```
import { Promise as BlueBirdPromise } from 'bluebird';

BlueBirdPromise.setScheduler((fn: any) => {
    setTimeout(fn, 0);
});

global.Promise = <any>BlueBirdPromise;
```

Comment: Note: `<any>BlueBirdPromise` is casting `BlueBirdPromise` to any. In newer versions we use `as`: `BlueBirdPromise as any`.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.